# my sago palm is yellowing

Tags: diagnosis

I bought 2 little sago palms in a small pot with glued stones around it.  I try to water it but can't tell if the soil is dry or wet because of the stones glued around them.  What should I do?

Comment: Welcome Michelle! Thanks for bringing us your question! I'm happy to see you're already getting some help! Would you please add pictures of the plant and its pot including a view of the soil with the stones, or without if you already removed them! Thanks!

Comment: We're different from some other sites, so I invite you to visit our [help]. [Ask] is a good place to start. If you have any questions about how we do things, leave a comment and someone will help you!  Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

The stones are decorative but do not help you when you want to know how dry the soil is. Sago Palms store water in the bulbous stem so over watering is number one problem.

Remove the stones and then you can tell when it needs to be watered